# Sounds issues for every update in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: sound, alsa, 20.04

Every update that I run through the "Software Updater" in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS messes up with my sound. In order to fix it I need to run `sudo alsa force-reload` right after every update.

Why is this happening and is there any permanent solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it is related to updating? It consistently works when you don't update? Which package are you updating?

Comment: Thanks, I reinstalled 20.04 LTS and the sound started to work without any issues.